Custom Nodes as Assets
Does anyone know how to extend custom nodes to support asset drops from the asset browser? If you go to the script templates > Custom Nodes sample and run it. You can add this custom node tree as an asset and it will appear in the asset browser, but when trying to drop it into the custom node tree nothing happens, there is a stop sign showing it is not allowed.


Are you trying to drag CustomNodeTree into the GeoNodes editor window with the CustomNodeTree as the active node tree? I don't think Blender will allow that cause its a cyclical reference. Try dragging it into a blank new GN tree.

@Jakemoyo no no, custom node tree into the same custom node tree.

Your answer doesn't make it clear. You have tried dragging it into a separate node tree?

@Jakemoyo in the screenshot you see a node tree named Custom Node Tree, this is from the "Custom Node" template script that ships with Blender. After running the script I right clicked on the "Custom Node Tree" name and added it as an asset, which you can see in the asset browser on the right. I then try to drag it from the asset browser back into the "Custom Node Tree" node editor. You can repeat these steps using the same "Custom Node" template.

Yeah, you can't drag a node tree into itself, that's the problem I'm describing. Try dragging it into a completely different node tree.
